# Vertical drop down menu with indicator for children

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, geometry, vertical-alignment

Here is a vertical drop down menu, but the problem is that the indicator (little arrow) should show that one item (link) has other objects (children). I would like something like this: [image]

And here is what I have

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link5</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubLink1</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">SubLink2</a>
                     <ul>
                         <li><a href="#">SubSubLink1</a></li>  
                         <li><a href="#">SubSubLink2</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">SubLink3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link6</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubLink4</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">SubLink5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav
{
    width: 230px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}

nav li a
{
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
} 

nav a:link
{
    color: #718785;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

nav li a:hover
{
    font-weight: bolder;
}

nav li a:active
{ 
    font-weight: bolder;
}

nav a:visited
{
    color: #718785;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

/*dropdown menu*/
nav ul ul
{
    display: none;
    margin-left: 230px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    float: left;
    height: 0;
    background-image: url('http://i58.tinypic.com/2exvv5i.png');
}

nav ul li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
    width: 230px;
    height: 40px;

}

nav li > a:after
{
   background-image: url('http://i57.tinypic.com/xcw6f5.png');
   width: 9px;
   height: 6px;
   margin: 10px; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ZEqL/5/

Comment: There is no way in current CSS to select “upwards”. The easiest solution would be to do this via markup – give those LI that have a submenu a class, and format them via that.

Comment: I would like to put a little arrow on li with children. Can I do this without jQuery?

Comment: jQuery is just a tool to make writing JavaScript easier. Of course you can do whatever you can do with jQuery without it as well – if you have the necessary knowledge …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in some way with CSS using `:before` pseudo-element like this:

- First change the hide element from the `ul` to `li`:

  ```
  nav ul ul {
    /*display:none; Remove this*/
  }
  nav ul ul li{
    display:none; /*Add this*/
  }
  ```

  <sub>Also don't forget to change the `:hover` event to show the li elements, review the fiddle</sub>
- Then use the `:before` to show the arrow:

  ```
  nav ul li > ul:before {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:-15px;
    background:url('yourarrow') no-repeat center;
  }
  ```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZEqL/8/)**

Comment: Yep @user3265921 search more about that and :after; allows you multiple things avoiding extra markup or JS in some cases.